# sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient works on windows 7 but fails on windows 8

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have some SSL client code (C#) which looks like:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"client.pfx"); 

X509Certificate2Collection x09s = new X509Certificate2Collection();

x09s.Add(cert);

TcpClient client = new TcpClient(controllerIP, port);

sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, OnCertificateValidation, 
               new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(SelectLocalCertificate));
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("", x09s, SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

This is communicating with a linux server running with openssl. It all works great when the client is Windows 7.  When I try on a Windows 8 client however, the AuthenticateAsClient always get an exception with the message: "Unable to read data from the transport connection. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

The LocalCertificateSelectionCallback function is called and returns properly.

What changed in Windows 8?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but still, I got same answer form AuthenticateAsClient in Windows 10.

AuthenticateAsClient was successful when I increased response time in client (TcpClient) and streams (NetworkStream, SslSteram).

But for some weird reason in Windows 10, after I dispose of connection objects (SslStream and TcpClient) and try to go through connection steps again, AuthenticateAsClient is successful each second time. (success, fail, success, fail ...).

For Windows 7 everything works perfectly.